# How to trigger a change, when adding new property in object in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, watch

I'm having the following initial structure of vuex state (in VueJS project):

```
state: {
    level1prop: null
}
```

And then I'm changing it dynamically and I'm mutating it into the following structure:

```
state: {
    level1prop: {
        level2prop: {
            level3prop: {
                "customKey1": { /* this is some object 1 */ },
                "customKey2": { /* this is some object 2 */ },
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will be then adding `"customKeyN": { /* this is some object N */ }` under the `level3prop` and what it's important for me is on every change to trigger a watcher, which is watching for a changes into the `level1prop` from the state.

Initially, in my mutation I was doing this update on the following way:

```
if (!state.hasOwnProperty("level1prop"))
    state["level1prop"] = {};
else if (state["level1prop"] === null || state["level1prop"] === undefined)
    state["level1prop"] = {};

if (!state["level1prop"].hasOwnProperty("level2prop"))
    state["level1prop"]["level2prop"] = {};
else if (state["level1prop"]["level2prop"] === null || state["level1prop"]["level2prop"] === undefined)
    state["level1prop"]["level2prop"] = {};

if (!state["level1prop"]["level2prop"].hasOwnProperty("level3prop"))
    state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"] = {};
else if (state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"] === null || state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"] === undefined)
    state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"] = {};

let payloadObj = {  "customKey1": { /* this is some object 1 */ }  };
state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"] = payloadObj;
```

And this is creating the structure on the way I want, but the watcher of changes is not triggered. Following the advises from [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) i refactor my code to a few different ways, but none of them is triggering the changes. Here is an example for latest option which I tried:

```
if (!state.hasOwnProperty("level1prop"))
    state = Object.assign(state, { "level1prop" : {} });
else if (state["level1prop"] === null || state["level1prop"] === undefined)
    state = Object.assign(state, { "level1prop" : {} });

if (!state["level1prop"].hasOwnProperty("level2prop"))
    state["level1prop"] = Object.assign(state["level1prop"], { "level2prop" : {} });
else if (state["level1prop"]["level2prop"] === null || state["level1prop"]["level2prop"] === undefined)
    state["level1prop"] = Object.assign(state["level1prop"], { "level2prop" : {} });

if (!state["level1prop"]["level2prop"].hasOwnProperty("level3prop"))
    state["level1prop"]["level2prop"] = Object.assign(state["level1prop"]["level2prop"], { "level3prop" : {} });
else if (state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"] === null || state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"] === undefined)
    state["level1prop"]["level2prop"] = Object.assign(state["level1prop"]["level2prop"], { "level3prop" : {} });

let payloadObj = {  "customKey 1": { /* this is some object 1 */ }  };
state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"] = Object.assign(state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"], payloadObj);
```

Again, this is creating the structure which I need, but watcher is still not triggered. A few other options that I tried, but were not triggering the change were:

```
...
state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"] = Object.assign({}, state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"], payloadObj);
...
```

and

```
...
Object.assign(state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"], payloadObj);
...
```

Is there any way to be able to trigger the watcher for a changes, in such a complex object state with so many nested levels?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the docs [Object Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats) section, you should better use the specifically designed Vue setter [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) to later add sub-levels to your state.

Then make sure your watcher specifies the [`deep`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) option, so that it is correctly triggered when your sub-levels change.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    level1prop: null,
  },
});

const state = store.state;

if (!state["level1prop"])
  Vue.set(state, "level1prop", {})

if (!state["level1prop"]["level2prop"])
  Vue.set(state["level1prop"], "level2prop", {})

if (!state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"])
  Vue.set(state["level1prop"]["level2prop"], "level3prop", {})

let payloadObj = {
  "customKey1": {
    hello: "world",
  },
};
state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"] = payloadObj;

setTimeout(() => {
  // Change an already existing key.
  state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"].customKey1.hello = "too";
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  // To add or remove keys, make sure to use again Vue.set or Vue.delete.
  state["level1prop"]["level2prop"]["level3prop"].customKey1.hello = "too";
  Vue.set(state["level1prop"]["level2prop"], "level3propSibling", {
    hi: "again",
  });
}, 2000);


new Vue({
  store: store,
  watch: {
    "$store.state": {
      // Make sure you specify the `deep` option
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        console.log(store.state);
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3"></script>
```